# Partial specialization of member variable and method

Tags: c++, templates, code-organization, template-specialization

I'm programming a simulation which should both work for 2D and 3D. Now I got objects which surface should be modified. At 3D the surface is a two-dimensional array while with 2D its one-dimensional. I use a template parameter to indicate which dimensional space I use. But when I'm specializing the type of my array I can't specialize the modifying function since it is expected in the specified class. And then I would have to copy all members into the specialized class.

```
template <class VectorType> class SimulationObject {
    void operateOnSurface();
};

template<> class SimulationObject<Vector2D> {
    char* surface;
 // Declaration of operateOnSurface expected here
};

template<> class SimulationObject<Vector3D> {
    char** surface;
// Declaration of operateOnSurface expected here
};

template<> void A<Vector2D>::operateOnSurface() {
}

template<> void A<Vector3D>::operateOnSurface() {
}
```

But I still want to avoid to copy the code for 2d and 3d since my surface-array and the modifying function are the only members that specify it. So is there another way?

Comment: How about abstracting your `surface` one time?  You can have two specializations of the abstract concept that the highest-factored methods use.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Vector2D and Vector3D, you could add a `static const int dimensions;` variable to both of them and access it with `VectorType::dimensions`.